# Having errors using MAX in JPA

Tags: jpa

I Have this JPA query which causes an error that i can't figure out why. This is the typed query :

```
SELECT max(t.EndTime) FROM Transactions t WHERE t.clientID = :clientID
```

What is should do is, get the last(most recent) transaction of the client. So to do that i am using some time field called transaction endtime. Is the query the problem ?

When i execute the query : `transactions = query.getSingleResult();`

This is the error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.sql.Timestamp cannot be cast to org.models.Transactions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should return the result in a `Timestamp` reference.

```
java.sql.Timestamp time = query.getSingleResult();
```